# Display text based on time of day PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to show opening and closing times throughout the week however on a Tuesday the time to open is at 10:30. It seems to want to sit at 10 or 11. I've tried 10.5 in the PHP variable, but that's not making a change. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // set it to the right value

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'));

if($weAreOpen) {
echo 'We are open for business';
} else {
echo 'We are closed';
}

/**
 * Test if we're open for business
 * @param string $day - day of week (ex: Monday)
 * @param string $hour - hour of day (ex: 9)
 * @return bool - true if open interval 
 */
function areWeOpen($day, $hour) {
$hour = (int)$hour;
switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
            }
        break;
    case 'Thursday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
                }
            break;
    case 'Friday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Saturday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
        if($hour >= 10 && $hour < 16) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
}
return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Send a `$minutes` variable and check `if ((($hour == 9 && $minutes >= 30) || $hour > 9) && $hour < 21)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass minutes as function parameter and use it in if condition like this

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // set it to the right value

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'), date('i'));

if($weAreOpen) {
echo 'We are open for business';
} else {
echo 'We are closed';
}

/**
 * Test if we're open for business
 * @param string $day - day of week (ex: Monday)
 * @param string $hour - hour of day (ex: 9)
 * @return bool - true if open interval 
 */
function areWeOpen($day, $hour, $minutes) {
$hour = (int)$hour;
switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        if($hour >= 11 && $hour < 21 || ($hour == 10 && $minutes >= 30)) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
            }
        break;
    case 'Thursday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
                }
            break;
    case 'Friday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Saturday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
        if($hour >= 10 && $hour < 16) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
}
return false;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read up on what `date('G')` actually does in the [PHP manual for date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It gives you the hour in an 24 hour format. So, naturally, there can never be a .5 hour.

To check for half hours you can for example get the minutes from here, but in general there is probably a better solution than to check all parts of the clock individually, e.g. checking if the time of the day is lower or greater than something.

Comment: No kidding: time manipulation is no fun.  Once you get done looking at all the individual components, you can change it all again to account for global time zones... Or you can use  php date manipulation functions and your life will be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

You cast your variable to an integer in the very first line of your function:

```
$hour = (int)$hour;
```

So any information after the hour number will be lost after that.

Removing that line would solve that.

By the way, I don't see any logic in your function that accounts for the Tuesday opening time.

You should probably decide on a format (real time or floats) first and adapt your logic accordingly. I would probably use a DateTime object to store all the information about the moment you are querying about and would give you the possibility to expand the function for holidays, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You should also send the minutes information to your function and check with it.

```
$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'), date('i'));

...
...

function areWeOpen($day, $hour, $minutes) {

 ...
 // check the minutes value as well
 ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to incorporate minutes and not only hours if you want to react on times like "10:30". Try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // set it to the right value

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'), date('i'));

if($weAreOpen) {
echo 'We are open for business';
} else {
echo 'We are closed';
}

/**
 * Test if we're open for business
 * @param string $day - day of week (ex: Monday)
 * @param string $hour - hour of day (ex: 9)
 * @param string $minute - minute (ex: 42)
 * @return bool - true if open interval 
 */
function areWeOpen($day, $hour, $minute) {
switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        if(($hour + $minute/60) >= 10.5 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
            }
        break;
    case 'Thursday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
                }
            break;
    case 'Friday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Saturday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
        if($hour >= 10 && $hour < 16) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
}
return false;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest what others already have, you need to include `minutes` if you want to check against a half hour. Though, I would also simply the rest of the code:

```
<?php

$weAreOpen = areWeOpen(date('l'), date('G'), date('i'));

if($weAreOpen) {
echo 'We are open for business';
} else {
echo 'We are closed';
}

/**
 * Test if we're open for business
 * @param string $day - day of week (ex: Monday)
 * @param string $hour - hour of day (ex: 9)
 * @param int $min - Minute of the hour
 * @return bool - true if open interval 
 */
function areWeOpen($day, $hour, $min) {
$hour = (int)$hour;
switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
    case 'Wednesday':
    case 'Thursday':
    case 'Friday':
    case 'Saturday':
        if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        if(($hour >= 11 && $hour < 21) || ($min >= 30 && $hour == 10)) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
        if($hour >= 10 && $hour < 16) {
            return true;
        }
        break;
}
return false;
}

?>
```